# Vim plugin cscope_quickfix.vim doesn't show the function name in quickfix window

Tags: regex, vim, vim-plugin

I am editing this vim plugin I got online to make use of commandline cscope to open quickfix window. I understand most of the file. The plugin is very old, so when I run it against my database, I don't see the function name.
I just get:

```
filename.cpp|linenumber| text from that line
main.cpp|23| returncode = say_hello();
```

The tool is using command line cscope which does return the original function.
Result from cscope:

```
filename.cpp function_name linenumber 'text from that line'
main.cpp see_top 23 returncode = say_hello();
```

I went into the plugin and found this line, which seems to be the culprit, but I can't understand what its saying or doing:

```
set efm=%f\ %*[^\ ]\ %l\ %m
```

Could someone please explain what it is trying to achieve. From the basic knowledge of regex, all I can tell is `%f` might be filename, then it ignores everything till the `%l` thus also ignoring the important function name I need to see.
How can I change the script to show me the function name as well?
Here is the vim plugin I have been talking about: [QuickFix plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=862)
Reason for using quickfix plugin: I am using vim 6 on development system (can't upgrade). I know I can compile the new version, but that is a bigger hastle as all the libraries would need updating.

Edit1: updated the title to be more direct.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by reading the following section of Vim's documentation and all the linked sections:

```
:help 'errorformat'
```

But the plugin has a few options, including one for disabling the use of the quickfix window. Worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I know about the option. I was hoping to keep it on. The cmd_output variable in the plugin does get the function name, it just gets masked by the command above. How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, could you please help with the "set efm" command? Where can I add the function so the plugin would work?

Comment: If I were you I would just do that in the plugin itself, using basic trial and error with `:help errorformat` open.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is stupid but I think it is worth trying it. Just delete

```
set efm=%f\ %*[^\ ]\ %l\ %m
```

in the plugin, so that Vim can use its default `'errorformat'`.

Comment: Thank you your response. The output window is better now. I can finally see the function name. But the "return" key doesn't take me the results anymore... Can you please help me? I am not good at vim scripting.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by that, try to elaborate. À propos, if you need something else than to show a function name in quickfix window, maybe you formulated your question incorrectly.

Comment: The quickfix plugin works by showing me the cscope output(without the function name). I click <return> and it takes me to the result file. But when I remove the line you suggested, it shows me the cscope output(with the function name), but pressing <return> doesn't take me to the result file.

Comment: Try to put away (comment, delete - it is up to you) all lines containing efm. If it works, good for you, if not, you should probably follow [romainl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641080/vim-plugin-cscope-quickfix-vim-doesnt-show-the-function-name-in-quickfix-window/32661545?noredirect=1#comment53254016_32645850).